# How to override instance variable property behavior during initialize class python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have one class Vehicle with property as color and BMW class has car_type as instance variable from Vehicle
from the following I get color property from BMW But is there any way I can overwrite the behavior color property of Vehicle in BMW class? so when I 
call bmw.car_type it execute not only color property but also return the value from  mycolor

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self):
        self._color = 'blue'

    @property
    def color(self):
        return self._color

class BMW:
    def __init__(self):
        self.car_type = Vehicle()

    @property
    def mycolor(self):
        return 'extra string from BMW'

bmw = BMW()
print(bmw.mycolor) # extra string form BMW
print(bmw.car_type.color) #blue
#I want to override the color property inside BMW class so I can call bmw.car_type.color to get the string without create extra property
print(bmw.car_type.color) #blue + extra string form BMW
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve with the `mycolor` property, do you want to override `Vehicle`'s `color` or just alter the value returned by it?

Comment: i want to alter the value of Vehicle's color by call BMW.car_type.color

Comment: What I think you want is for BMW to inherit Vehicle, then you can just re-use the color property. At least, that is the general approach to these problems.

Comment: problem is I cannot make BMW to inherit from Vehicle

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use the term "override" here, that implies inheritance. Your vehicle should take a color as an argument, and then your `BMW` instance will pass the color to the `Vehicle` constructor

Answer (score 0):

In your snippet BMW class does not inherit Vehicle, if I understood correctly this is the behavior you want for BMW class:

```
class Vehicle:
  def __init__(self):
    self._color = 'blue'

  @property
  def color(self):
    return self._color

class BMW(Vehicle):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

  @property
  def color(self):
    return self._color + 'extra string from BMW'
car = Vehicle()
print(car.color) #blue

bmw = BMW()
print(bmw.color) #blue extra string from BMW'
```

Comment: as my questions mentions. I need to override and use instance variable like call `bmw.car_type.color` to get the value